# Probability & Random Variables -- probability of $k$ machines remaining on day $i$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a question that Im struggling with that has to do with probability, random variables, and (possibly) indicators

The scenario is that you have n machines, and each machine has a probability p of working. Every remaining machine is tested everyday, and the ones that don't work are thrown away. $X_{i}$ is the random variable that represents how many machines remain after i days. We start with $X_{0} = n$

The distribution of $X_1$ is just $P[X_1=k] = {n\choose k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ I believe

The next part asks for the distribution of $X_2$, but that's where I'm confused. Doesn't that depend on the previous distribution and doesn't p change accordingly each time? But we are asking for the unconditional probability distribution so we cant use the first part

I know that the probability of one machine remaining on day 1 is p. and then the probability of the same machine remaining on day 2 is I think $p^2$ but Im not 100% sure? So would I be correct is saying the distribution for $X_t$ is just ${n\choose k}p^{tk} (1-p)^{n-k}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.  The probability that a machine is still working by day $t$ is $p^t$, so the probability that is is not working on day $t$ is not $1-p$, but $1-p^t$.  The answer should be $$\Pr(X_t=k)={n\choose k}p^{tk} (1-p^t)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Hi! Thank you :) Quick question, then on that note, is it valid to say that the probability that at least 1 machine remains on day t is ${n\choose 1}p^{t} $?

Comment: @Melanie No.  The probability that at least one machine is working is $1$ minus the probability that all have failed: $1-\left(1-p^t\right)^n$